# htaccess URL rewrite - requested URL not found on server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need to hide one folder while loading like `Uniimart1609/S/page.php` to  `Uniimart1609/page.php`
in linux

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule Home_Page.php$ S/Home_Page.php 
</IfModule>
```

is redirected `http://Uniimart1609/Home_Page.php` this is working fine, but when i rewrite the htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /S/$1.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

getting The requested URL /S/Home_Page.php was not found on this server. Pleas help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Uniimart1609/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /S/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/S/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ S/$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i tried above code but url is not changing from http://localhost/Uniimart1609/S/Home_Page.php to http://localhost/Uniimart1609/Home_Page.php while loading

Comment: Not working,help. http://localhost/Uniimart1609 is loading from index.php from there header is redirected to S/Home_Page.php

Comment: What happens when you enter URL as `localhost/Uniimart1609/S/Home_Page.php`? Are there more rules in your htaccess?

Comment: page is loading but url is not changing means localhost/Uniimart1609/S/Home_Page.php to localhost/Uniimart1609/Home_Page.php the /S/ folder is still there ,if i try to load like localhost/Uniimart1609/Home_Page.php  it shows 404

Comment: You didn't reply on other rules. Are there more rules in this htaccess? Also what is location of this htaccess file?

Comment: no i did not add any other rules, the above code i copied directly to my htaccess file, the location of htaccess file is localhost/Uniimart1609